# High number of reads in SQL Profiler

Tags: sql-server, profiling

I am looking at some performance turning of my queries, and notice that Query Profiler is showing a HIGH number of reads, but low durations.

[image]

Is that an accumalation of reads? It seems to increase all the time - but the query it's self, seems quick, as far as 'duration' goes.

Is this something to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HIGH number of reads, but low durations.

This can be a sign of execution plans which use parallelism. You may look, also, at `CPU` vs. `Duration`. If `CPU` is greater than `Duration` then this hypothesis is true.

> It seems to increase all the time

*Increasing value of Reads (logical reads)*

Maybe, another concurrent connection insert data.